# How to send response back to api in php in dominknow

Tags: php, scorm

I am Using dominknow plateform from there they send a api hit on my server file and I get that data and store to mysql database .

All things are working find , but I am not able to send response back to that api that I have recevied the data correctly, so message is displaying "That your Pens package has not been sent to target location.

## This type of response they wanted

> https://demo.authr.it:A490CE33-CF8F-29B5-453D-D2A6482C54FD,HTTPStatus=200,error=0,error-text=collect (https://demo.authr.it:A490CE33-CF8F-29B5-453D-D2A6482C54FD,HTTPStatus=200,error=0,error-text=collect)
>   command received and
>   understood,version=1.0.0,pens-data={"generic":"https://share.cda.dominknow.one/e55c01eb58d4d8524272efe393e6c290/e710745c-5db9-3595-864f-75571171c3eb/xapi","url":"https://share.cda.dominknow.one/e55c01eb58d4d8524272efe393e6c290/e710745c-5db9-3595-864f-75571171c3eb/A490CE33-CF8F-29B5-453D-D2A6482C54FD"},

=================================

## And this response they recieving from my below code, I dont know why error, error-text-version not being sent

> https://mydemo.authr.it:6F095428-DD20-5278-7B92-56375FC4745E,HTTPStatus=200,error=,error-text=,version=,pens-data=
>   (https://mydemo.authr.it:6F095428-DD20-5278-7B92-56375FC4745E,HTTPStatus=200,error=,error-text=,version=,pens-data=)

=================================

```
$all_data=$_POST;
$file = fopen('/var/www/html/api/rec_file.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file,json_encode($all_data));

fclose($file);
$pens_version         =  $_POST['pens-version'];

?>
error=0
error-text=collect
version=<?php echo $pens_version; ?>
pens-data=
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to send a response in JSON.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = array(
    'error'=>0,
    'error-text'=>'collect',
    'version'=>$_POST['pens-version'],
    'pens-data'=>''
);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: In the response they receive from you, we can see that all the expected attributes are undefined. Did you set the header 'Content-Type' to 'application/json'?

Answer (score 0):

The Response need to be in Plain Text as given below with PHP

```
header('Content: text/plain');
echo "error=0\r\n";
echo "error-text=collect\r\n";
echo "version=1.0.0\r\n";
echo "pens-data="
```